# Char array comparing and while loop not working properly in C

Tags: c, file-io, while-loop, strcmp, strncpy

I have this function named CheckEmployee. It opens a text file and check if the id the user entered exists in the record:

```
void CheckEmployee()
{
    system("CLS");
    char empID[5];

    printf("Key in Employee ID: ");
    scanf("%s", &empID);

    FILE *fp = fopen("Employees.txt", "r");
    char lineOfText[40];

    while (fgets(lineOfText, 40, fp))
    {
        char id[6];
        strncpy(id, lineOfText, 5);
        id[5] = 0;

        if (id == empID)
        {
            printf("Hello?");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The texfile contains the following:

```
E0001de Guzman, Franz Miguel C.         
E0002de Guzman, Fernan Ralph C.
```

with 40 characters each line including white spaces.
The problem is:

1. The `while` loops 4 times.(Should be twice only since there is only 2 records to traverse.)
2. The program has a runtime error in `if (id == empID)`. But when I replaced it with `if (strcmp(id, empID) == 0)`, the answer is false.

**UPDATE**: `strcmp` is now working. thanks to @barak manos. The `while` looping 4 times still persists, but I get the result that I want.

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", &empID);` to `scanf("%s", empID);` for start.

Comment: thanks @G.Samaras, that removed my warning.

Comment: A possible reason for the first point could be that you are just reading the first 40 characters and forget to read the end of line (`\n`). Try calling `getchar()` after each iteration.

Comment: `fgets` reads the whole line, including the `\n`. There could be blank lines at the end of the file.

Comment: Your employee IDs seem like 7 character long strings, so they need 8 bytes of space (remember the terminating `NULL`) but `id` is 5. The `scanf` results in a buffer overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3386109, in this version he is specifying the total number of characters to read.

Comment: @NikBougalis: I think you'll find the employee ID is E0001, etc, and the `de` is part of the family name of the de Guzman's.

Comment: @rendon, yup you're right. I didn't notice the comment that the lines have white space at the end. I always just have a buffer that's much bigger than the input lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, the `char empID[5]` and `char id[6]` look suspiciously short for your input.

Second, the value of expression `id == empID` is always false, since you are essentially comparing memory addresses of two statically allocated arrays.

The expression `strcmp(id,empID) == 0` should yield the result you're looking for, **assuming** that the `id` and `empID` arrays are sufficiently large to store the text that you are reading into them.

Keep in mind that string routines such as `strcmp`, `strcpy`, `strlen`, `printf` expect null-terminated strings as input. So you have to make sure that each `char` array used for that purpose is large enough to store the input text plus an additional `\0` character.

Comment: So it is ok to have a char array that holds my ID way bigger than what I should store onto it?

Comment: @Gatherer: Of course, but ideally, if you know the maximum size of the text then you should allocate your array to that size + 1.

Comment: @Gatherer: You're welcome. Don't forget to make sure that a 0 character comes after the last character in your string. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if you find it suitable, by clicking ob the V next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `strcmp()` to compare strings.  You're comparing whether your two variables have the same address — and they don't.

Note that the `empID` isn't long enough to hold `E0001` with a null terminator; you should be consistent in your array sizing.  Your string length of 40 for the line is perilously small, too.  I'd probably use 4096 for the line size, and complain if the line presented was actually longer than 39 or 40.  It's also a good idea to use `fgets(lineOfText, sizeof(lineOfText), fp)` with the `sizeof` to specify the array size.  This means you only have to change one line of code if you want to change the size of the array — and that's the declaration of the array.

Comment: I know exactly how many numbers of characters per record will be existing in the text file, so I use `fgets(lineOfText, 40, fp)`. Each line consists of exactly 40 characters including white spaces. I thought that your way will be used perfectly for the files that have irregular number of characters. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: It depends in part on whether you trust your data files, and also on whether you've correctly accounted for newlines and terminal nulls.  Personally, I'd not take the risk of not detecting flawed data; YMMV.  Your code will handle short records (modestly short records, missing a few bytes) sanely.  It won't spot over-long records.  When you've been programming longer, you'll appreciate that programs should withstand faulty inputs — at this stage, it is perhaps not so critical, but keep it in mind that robust programs don't make assumptions about the quality of their input (think Heartbleed!).

Answer (score 0):

**you should do like this :**

```
 while (fgets(lineOfText, 40, fp))
    {
        char id[6];
        strncpy(id, lineOfText, 5);

        id[5] ='\0';  // add null to end of id.

        if (strcmp(id,empID)==0) // here compare string
        {
            printf("Hello?");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got your point. I've learned that char are int too. They don't care of you give them integer. So, `id[5]=0` is the same as `id[5] = '\0'`. But I appreciate you giving helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: instead of thanks you can up vote the answer if it is correct.